# Background image with Carousel effect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to create a layout with a fullscreen background image and some UI elements on top of it. The twist is this:

I would like the background image to swipeable like a carousel, but I would like the UI elements to stay in place. That is if I swipe the screen, the background image should slide to the side and a new image should replace it. I know about `CarouselPage`, but it seems to me that it won't do the trick, since a `Page` can have only one child which it replaces on swipe, meaning that the UI elements would be descendants of the `CarouselPage` and therefore would also be animated.

I am guessing I need some sort of custom renderer here, but how should I go about designing it? Should it be one fullscreen Image control replaced be another fullscreen Image control with the UI elements on top of it? And how can I do this? Or is there an all together better approach?

I am developing for iOS and Android using Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds cool. Let us know how you get on with that. :)

Comment: are the UI elements going to be interact-able at all by the user? or are they purely for displaying information?

Comment: They will be interactive. A couple og buttons and labels basically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like [repeating myself](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/80946/#Comment_80946) much, and I think that multiple layers of actionable items can lead to confusion, but the problems appeals to me and I can see a niche for this kind of UI, so here's my take on your question.

Let's assume this is the (`Xamarin.Forms.`)`Page` you want to render with a custom carousel background:

```cs
public class FunkyPage : ContentPage
{
    public IList<string> ImagePaths { get; set; }

    public FunkyPage ()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Spacing = 12,
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Foo" },
                new Label { Text = "Bar" },
                new Label { Text = "Baz" },
                new Label { Text = "Qux" },
            }
        };

        ImagePaths = new List<string> { "red.png", "green.png", "blue.png", "orange.png" };
    }
}
```

The renderer for iOS could look like this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (FunkyPage), typeof (FunkyPageRenderer))]

public class FunkyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    UIScrollView bgCarousel = new UIScrollView (RectangleF.Empty) {
        PagingEnabled = true,
        ScrollEnabled=true
    };
    List<UIImageView> uiimages = new List<UIImageView> ();

    protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var sub in uiimages)
            sub.RemoveFromSuperview ();

        uiimages.Clear ();

        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            var page = e.NewElement as FunkyPage;
            foreach (var image in page.ImagePaths) {
                var uiimage = new UIImageView (new UIImage (image));
                bgCarousel.Add (uiimage);
                uiimages.Add (uiimage);
            }
        }
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        Add (bgCarousel);
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
    }

    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();
        bgCarousel.Frame = View.Frame;
        var origin = 0f;
        foreach (var image in uiimages) {
            image.Frame = new RectangleF (origin, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
            origin += View.Frame.Width;
        }
        bgCarousel.ContentSize = new SizeF (origin, View.Frame.Height);
    }
}
```

This was tested and works. Adding a UIPageControl (the dots) is easy on top of this. Autoscrolling of the background is trivial too.

The process is similar on Android, the overrides are a bit different.

Comment: This looks really promising, Stephane. I am not really sure I understand it completely, though. I get that you are making a custom page here and using the collection of images from imagePaths to populate a bunch of UIScrollViews and that each of these UIScrollViews represents a background. 

What I don't understand is why you are making the e.NewElement != null check? I don't really understand the code in ViewWillLayoutSubviews either, except that it has something to do with sizing.

Also. How did you test this? How to trigger the 'swipe effect' (that is replacing one image with another)? Thks

Comment: tested on simulator and device